# Jquery "hide on load" causing a Javascript error

Tags: jquery, html, syntax

I am trying to write a menu whose subitems vanish when the page is loaded.

If you need full HTML, I will copy it, however it just consists of a bunch of DIVs, the items under the headers have a class of `subitems`.

I have managed to do what I need via:

```
   $(document).ready(

    $(".subitems").hide()

   );
```

However, in Chrome, despite it working fine, I get the following error in the console:

[image]
 (Using picture as I can't copy the formatting well)

When I remove the above code, the error goes. I guess I have done something wrong, but I can't see it and so far it works in every browser I have tested.

Any suggestions on either:

1. Have I done something wrong?
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the anonymous function(`function() { }`) wrapper, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".subitems").hide();
});
```

It's trying to do `$(".subitems").hide().call()` under the covers when it executes the `ready` handlers...but this isn't a function.  Instead, it's executing *immediately* (not on `document.ready`) and throwing an error when `document.ready` tries to run the *result* of `.hide()`.

Just to note, there's a shorter form of the above as well:

```
$(function() {
 $(".subitems").hide();
});
```

Comment: Bloody hell you are good! An answer in 30 seconds!... Works. I don't suppose you can post a link to somewhere that explains it in a bit more detail? It is brilliant that it works (so will mark as answer), however I would be lying if I said I understood why/how.

Comment: ok... edited as I typed that comment! Many thanks! .... Just one thing that confuses me, why does it actually work and cause an error instead of just causing an error? (done +1, but have to wait to mark as answer)

Comment: @Wil - Ok so `.ready()` takes a handler (like `.click()`, etc), it expects a *function* to run when the "event" (not a real event in this case) happens.  What *was* happening is it was running `$(".subitems").hide()` *immediately* (like any other function call) then the *result* of that is what's being passed into `.ready()`.  The problem is that's a jQuery object that `.hide()` returns (for chaining), not a `function` that has the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call).

Answer (score 3):

As the error is solved, maybe there is another way to do it.
I guess you did'nt really want to hide on page-load, but want to hide if javascript is active(you use ready to have access to the objects). If I'm right, there is an easier way. Give the `<html>` a class

```
$('html').addClass('scripted')
```

(as `<html>` is known everytime/everywhere, you already can do this inside the `<head>`)

...then you will be able to hide the objects via css and don't have to wait for ready()

```
html.scripted .subitems{display:none}/*only hidden if js is off*/
```

Comment: I can't mark as answer as the question was really about that specific problem (Which Nick solved), however, I really like this approach and will probably go with (a slight modification of) it. Thanks.