# how to load accordion first before content?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion constructed similar to the demo here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

If you browse the above with IE you will see that the content load first before the accordion kicks in to structure content into the accordion nicely.

My question is whether it is possible to get the accordion loaded first and then load the content only after that. This is so that we will not see the raw content first before it got put into the accordion.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: I don't experience what you describe in IE. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the content in the accordian or the content of the rest of the page?

Comment: CodeMonkey: I was using ie8 but it happens in ie7 too actually

Comment: Kamal: I meant the content inside the accordion. The content actually gets loaded first before the accordion kicks in and put all the contents into the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set `display: none` in your CSS (maybe even inline for speed) for all accordion content divs, but never forget about the people without Javascript.

I think all solutions will have some disadvantages for certain users. And if your webpage loads fast, it's a matter of milliseconds to load the accordion after all...

Comment: After I set it to display none at the start of the page, where should be the point where I display it back? I am using php. Is it possible to display it back after php construct the whole thing?

Comment: Let me answer my own question :) This seems to work. I set #accordion {visibility:hidden;} in css and set jQuery("#accordion ").css('visibility','visible'); in document ready

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way to do similar is to give inside the head a className to the `<html>` using javascript, what gives me the ability to use different CSS-selectors weither JS is enabled or not.
Read the description here: [Jquery "hide on load" causing a Javascript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001730/jquery-hide-on-load-causing-a-javascript-error/4001765#4001765)

How it works you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HTrTA/

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your links are helpful. I have partially implemented your solution.